# How to safely truncate a quoted string?

Tags: python, urllib

I have the following string:

```
Customer sale 88% in urm 50
```

Quoted with `urllib.parse.quote`, it becomes:

```
Customer%20sale%2088%25%20in%20urm%2050%27
```

Then I need to limit its length to a maximum of 30 characters and I use `value[:30]`.

The problem is that it becomes `"Customer%20sale%2088%25%20in%"` which is not valid:
The last % is part of %20 from quoted string and makes it an invalid quoted string.

I don't have control over the original string, and the final result needs to have a maximum 30 length, so I can't truncate it beforehand.

What approach would be feasible?

Comment: Do you want it to give `Customer%20sale%2088%25%20in` removing the trailing `%` ?

Comment: in this case yes. oBut if it was 31 in length would have to remove 2 characters. Should be made safe for any situation.

Comment: A `.strip('%20')` will handle this situation, may not every case.

Comment: `"Customer%20sale%2088%25%20in%20urm%2050%27"[:30]`  yields `'Customer%20sale%2088%25%20in%2'`, which has a part of `%20`, what do you want to do in that case?

Comment: @Ayxan, Should give `Customer%20sale%2088%25%20in` as per my understanding.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`urllib.quote` uses percent-encoding as defined in [RFC 3986](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986.html#section-2.1). This means that encoded character will always be of the form `"%" HEXDIG HEXDIG`.

So you simply can delete any trailing rest of the encoding by looking for a % sign in the last two characters.

For example:

```
>>> s=quote("Customer sale 88% in urm 50")[:30]
>>> n=s.find('%', -2)
>>> s if n < 0 else s[:n]
'Customer%20sale%2088%25%20in'
```

Comment: How do we know for sure that there is a trailing part to be removed? What about the cases the ending is nicely divided into something valid?

Comment: @Ayxan You are correct; when % is not found the last char will be truncated. Updated the answer accordingly.

Comment: What if OP decided to have a limit of `19` characters, which yields `'Customer%20sale%208'` (notice the trailing part of 2088). Would your code handle that case? How do we know for sure that the part after `%` is 2 characters long?

Comment: Yes it would. See the RFC for how the encoding is specified.

Comment: Yields `Customer%20sale%208` when limit is `[:19]`. Is that what OP asked for? Part of `2088` is still there

Comment: @Ayxan `%2088` is a single blank character, followed by the two digits `88`. Percent encoding is always a single percent sign followed by exactly two digits.

Comment: that clarifies everything. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

What about looking for dangling percentage marks?

```
value = value[:30]
if value[-1] == "%":
    value = value[:-1]
elif value[-2] == "%":
    value = value[:-2]
print(value)
```

Comment: Or `re.sub(r'%\d?\Z', '', value)`

Answer (score 0):

The encoded string will be always in the format of `%HH`. You want the string length to be maximum of 30characters with a valid encoding. So, probably the best solution I can think of:

```
from urllib.parse import quote
string= "Customer sale 88% in urm 50"
string=quote(string)
string=string[:string[:30].rfind("%")]
print(string)
```

Output:

```
string=string[:string[:30].rfind("%")]
```

**Solution:**

After the encoding, you may get a string of any length, the following one line of code will be enough to achieve your requirement in a very optimized way.

```
 string=string[:string[:30].rfind("%")]
```

**Explanation:**

It first extracts `30 characters` from the `quoted string` then searches for `%` from the right end. The position of `%` from the right end will be used to extract the string. Voilaa!! You got your result.

**Alternate approach:**

Instead of `string=string[:string[:30].rfind("%")]` you can do like this too `string=string[:string.rfind("%",0,30)]`

Note: I extracted the string and stored it back to showcase how it works, if you do not want to store then you can simply use like `print(string[:string[:30].rfind("%")])` to display the results

[image]

**Hope it helps...**

Comment: @martineau, Yes I extracted and assigned it back to a variable "string" to just showcase the example, if the user doesn`t want to store then we can simply use it print instead of assigning it to display the result.

Comment: @martineau


print(string[:string[:30].rfind("%")])
print(string)

Output will be like:

Customer%20sale%2088%25%20in                                                                                                     
Customer%20sale%2088%25%20in%20urm%2050

Comment: I think it's confusing (obviously). Also `string` is the name of a built-in Python module, so it's general a good idea not to use them as variable names.

Comment: @martineau, Please check the answer now...

if you don't want to store the result in a new variable or same variable then you can simply extract the wanted information and print it.

It will be like a view, memory will not be assigned.

Hope it clarifies...

Comment: Wouldn't that edit change the output to `Customer%20sale%2088%25%20in`?

Comment: No, we are just slicing the information, a="abc" print(a[1]) will give 'b' as output but the actually 'a' contains abc... if we store it like a=a[1] print(a) then a will contain only 'b' instead of abc because now only we assigned before we are only referencing not assigning the result

Answer (score 0):

How about putting the individual characters in a list and then count and strip?
Rough example:

```
from urllib import quote

s = 'Customer sale 88% in urm 50'

res = []
for c in s:
    res.append(quote(c))

print res # ['C', 'u', 's', 't', 'o', 'm', 'e', 'r', '%20', 's', 'a', 'l', 'e', '%20', '8', '8', '%25', '%20', 'i', 'n', '%20', 'u', 'r', 'm', '%20', '5', '0']
print len(res)

current_length = 0
for item in res:
    current_length += len(item)

print current_length # 39

while current_length > 30:
    res = res[:-1]
    current_length = 0
    for item in res:
        current_length += len(item)

print "".join(res) # Customer%20sale%2088%25%20in
```

That way you will not end up cutting in the middle of a quoting character. And in case you need a different length in the future, you just need to modify the while-loop. Well, code can be made more clean as well ;)